# Columna con datos duplicados en PowerBI

Tags: powerbi

Estoy creando un reporte en PowerBI y los datos con los que estoy trabajando estan en un excel y etoy teniendo problemas en cuanto a informacion duplicada, voy a tratar de explicar lo mejor posible la situacion.

La informacion cruda original no la puedo editar ya que proviene de un powerapps, por lo que estoy creando un excel copia que es donde hago las modificaciones para corregir esta duplicidad, el archivo consta de muchas columnas pero para la explicación solo tomare algunas: PAIS, CODIGO DE TIENDA, NÚMERO DE ITEMS TOTALES DE LA TIENDA, NÚMERO DE ITEMS, el proceso en la APP hace que el usuario cargue un codigo de tienda, la cantidad de item totales que hay en esa tienda, la cantidad de items que va a trabajar y posteriormente de los items a trabajar debe cargar ciertos datos para los items donde encuentres atipicidades, por ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto hace que para cada fila se dupliquen los valores de NÚMERO DE ITEMS TOTALES DE LA TIENDA y NÚMERO DE ITEMS, lo que necesito es que desde el powerBI pueda modificar los datos para que queden asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Actualmente en el excel copia lo que hago es ordenar por el codigo de tienda y en una columna adicional comparo si el valor de la celda es igual a la anterior y de ser asi limpio esos valores, pero necesito encontrar alguna forma de hacerlo automatico, porque esto se debe realizar 02 veces al dia todos los dias.

Comment: No entiendo... Desde Power Query no puedes modificar esas consultas y eliminar duplicados?

Comment: Desde Power Query solo puedo eliminar el registro/fila completa y eso no es lo que necesito, lo que requeiro es que el valor se cambie a cero o vacio, como se ve en las imagenes